# C# class instance field default value assignment plus default constructor equals double assignment?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and read that instance fields were initialized before a default constructor call. Does that mean that they are doubly initialized?

```
class MyClass
{
  public int value;

}
```

Would that mean that value gets the default 0 then the the default constructor is called and assigns 0 again?

Comment: +1 for your query. No, instance fields are not doubly initialized. They are not initialized during default constructor. You can check the same in debug mode.

Comment: That is what is confusing me. From msdn: "If a class does not have a constructor, a default constructor is automatically generated and default values are used to initialize the object fields. For example, an int is initialized to 0." Maybe I'm interpreting it wrong.

Comment: This indeed is formulated in a way that can easily be misunderstood. As it stands, it reads as if the fields are initialized with default values by the default constructor. This is not the case. The fields are initialized to default values, regardless of the existing constructors.

Comment: @user943870, Jon has given a nice explanation.

Comment: @user943870 - as new user dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the parameterless constructor created by the compiler *doesn't* perform an assignment to the field unless you specify a variable initializer. So in a class like this:

```
class Test
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c;
}
```

... the generated constructor looks like this in IL:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       22 (0x16)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stfld      int32 Test::a
  IL_0007:  ldarg.0
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0009:  stfld      int32 Test::b
  IL_000e:  ldarg.0
  IL_000f:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0014:  nop
  IL_0015:  ret
} // end of method Test::.ctor
```

Note the assignments to `a` and `b` but not `c`. Normally the difference between explicitly assigning a value of `0` and leaving it to be the default value is not observable, but it's present in the IL. (A subclass which decided to call some virtual method *before* calling the base class constructor could demonstrate the difference, although I suspect that would violate the CLS.)

Comment: @Jon, +1. I ran the code (C#) in debug mode. I could place breakpoints for a and b but not for c. It is the same behavior as you have mentioned (through IL code)

Comment: After thinking about it, your example raised another question. I thought the initialization order for your example would be instance fields, base constructor(in this case the system.object, i think), then instance constructor. Looking at your output, it looks like the instance constructor called the base constructor. Am I reading that incorrectly?

Comment: @user943870: Yes - at the IL level, it's just a call to the instance constructor, which is responsible for executing variable initializers and calling base constructors (or chaining to other constructors in the same class).

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.